# Redirect 301 in .htaccess not accepting slash

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've got a WordPress blog that I'm trying to redirect to a new domain.  The 301 redirect works, but it redirects to newdomain.comnew-post instead of newdomain.com/new-post.

Somehow, it's stripping out the slash.  Here's the code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Redirect 301 /old-post/ http://www.newdomain.com/new-post/
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be happening unless there's also a redirect happening at the `www.newdomain.com` site. You need to make sure that isn't happening.

Another possibility is that maybe mod_alias (the `Redirect` directive) and mod_rewrite (all the rewrite rules for wordpress) may be interfering with each other. Both get applied to the same URI (when it's `/old-post/` in the same URL-file mapping process pipeline. You could try removing the `Redirect` and stick to mod_rewrite, before wordpress' rules get applied at all. Try something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^old-post/(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/new-post/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a solution for this exact scenario, but it did solve the problem where the slash character got removed from the URL it was redirecting to.

My code was similar to this:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com
Redirect 301 /old-post/ http://www.newdomain.com/new-post/
```

The solution was to add a slash after the first line:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com/
Redirect 301 /old-post/ http://www.newdomain.com/new-post/
```

One could also try:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 ^/old-post/ http://www.newdomain.com/new-post/
```